# Forward Slashes ('/') Are Not Getting Created While Appending - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

In success of ajax return, on the success state, I run this append:

```
$('hello').append('
 <div class="row" style="background-image: url("/page/12/image-' + user[i]['id'] + '"); height: 155px;" ></div>')
```

I have couple of more lines, and everything works fine. However, on this line, for some reason this line is getting created in my `view:source` as:

```
<div class="row" style="background-image: url(" profile page 12 image 1.png") height: 155px"></div>
```

And the image doesn't get created because it has deleted the forward slashes ('/') while appending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just nested your quotes wrong, forgetting to escape the innermost single quotes.

I stepped through your example and got this to work

HTML:

```
<div class="hello"></div>
```

Js (included jQuery 1.8.3):

```
$('.hello').append('<div class="row" style="background-image: url(\'/page/12/image-' + 5 + '\'); height: 155px;"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue appear to be mixing double and single quotes within string . Try adding `id` `#` or `class` `.` selector before `hello`

```js
  var user = {
      0: {
        id: "cats"
      }
    },
    i = 0;

  var elem = $("<div />", {
    "class": "row",
    "css": {
      "backgroundImage": "url(http://lorempixel.com/155/155/" + user[i].id + ")",
      "height": "155px"
    }
  });

  $(".hello").append(elem);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="hello"></div>
```

Comment: I tried removing `+ <div class=row style=background-image: url(/page/12/image-"' + user[i]['id'] + '); height: 65px;` but it didn't work either. Only difference in view:source is quotes inside `url( )` removed.

Comment: Try without single quotes included `"<div class=row style=background-image: url(/page/12/image-" 
        + user[i].id+ "); height: 155px;></div>"`

Comment: emipac's answer was a quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

This way it will work:

```
$('hello').append('<div class="row" style="background-image: url(\'/page/12/image-' + user[i]['id'] + '\'); height: 155px;" ></div>')
```